# AWS Personalize: Failure reason Dataset has fewer than 1000 interactions

Tags: amazon-web-services, recommendation-engine, amazon-personalize

I am trying to create an AWS Personalize solution for the first time and I am able to import all the needed data sets but then it fails when I want to start.
[image]

And when I enter the solution overview

[image]

In my first attempts to import the interactions dataset it failed due to <1000 reason. Then I imported one with +2000 and worked. Once all the imports worked then the Start option was enabled, and this error happens.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the 1000 interactions must be distinct, got it after contacting AWS support.